# create a function that takes another function into itself

Tags: javascript

```
spread(someFunction, [1, true, "Foo", "bar"] )  // is the same as...
someFunction(1, true, "Foo", "bar")
```

I wrote this code but got some errors:

```
function spread(func, args) {
    func();
}
function func(args){
    console.log(args[0] + args[1]);
}
spread(func,[5,6])
```

TypeError: args is undefined, but I can't define it because it will be defined when call the function.

> spread(func,[5,6])

And i can't use variable either. I can just this kind of function. (This is a test)

Comment: You call `func()` without passing any arguments to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only 2 ways to implement such function in JS. One which is generating a string that expresses the function call and evaluate it and the other using Function.prototype.apply.

```
spread(add, [1, 2]); //3

function add(num1, num2) { return num1 + num2; }

function spread(fn, args) {
    return fn.apply(null, args);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the arguments to func and also return it if you want to keep the result in a variable.

```
function spread(func, args) {
    return func(args);
}
function func(args){
    console.log(args[0] + args[1]);
    //do something more, maybe:
    return (args[0] + args[1])
}
var result = spread(func,[5,6])
```

Comment: Thanks but i got this error in the IDE of test script :
/runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:256
                   throw ex;
                    ^
TestError: Expected: 3, instead got: 1,2undefined